# ExtJS 4, What should dateFormat be in Model?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

From server I receive such data:

```
expirationDate : "2014-08-27T22:00:00.000+0000"
```

and in MVC ExtJS 4 in Model I have this:

```
fields: [ 
    ...
    {name: "expirationDate", type: Ext.data.Types.DATE, dateFormat:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz"},
    ...
```

But the main problem is that `dateFormat`. Which should I choose for my date sample? This one doesn't word correctly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the model you would use

```
{ name: "expirationDate", type: "date", dateFormat: 'c' }
```

`dateFormat` simply uses `Ext.Date.parse()` which matches the PHP date() function.

[PHP date() formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Your format appears to be `ISO 8601 date`

Comment: Actually the problem was in IE. I tried to find some format but every time I received `undefined`. But using `dateFormat: 'c'` helped me to receive data as a Date so I managed to parse it. **Thank you very much!**